c++ warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths

warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths...

I know what it means, because the for loops don't return something when the data is empty.
How should I fix it?
template<typename T>
auto get(std::string argument_name) -> T {
    if (argument_name.length() <= 2) {
        argument_name = "-" + helpers::convert_string_tolower(argument_name);
    } else if (argument_name.length() >= 2) {
        argument_name = "--" + helpers::convert_string_tolower(argument_name);
    }

    for (const auto &p_n: parser.storage | std::views::keys) {
        for (const auto &[a_s_n, a_l_n] : parser.storage[p_n] | std::views::keys) {
            if (argument_name == a_s_n || argument_name == a_l_n) {
                ArgumentNamePair a_p = std::make_pair(a_s_n, a_l_n);
                if (parser.storage[p_n][a_p].contains("value")) {
                    return std::get<T>(parser.storage[p_n][a_p]["value"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my main function where I get this warning:
ArgumentParser program("");
program.get<bool>("argument_1"); // here i get the warning.

The problem here is that I can't return a NULL because I specified the datatype here:
program.get<bool>("argument_name");


Throw an exception if the code reaches the bottom of the function.  Or use std::expected  (needs C++23)

Or return a std::optional<T>

@RichardCritten that worked for my solution :) thanks.

if your code can't establish postcondition then throw exception, or return optional if the caller should be able to recover, if the code goes where it shouldn't then use std::unreachable. But your code looks strange, because it never returns anything, either recursively calling the same function or returning nothing.

@MariusRomeiser -- the problem here is that i can't return a NULL -- If the data type is default constructible, then putting return {}; at the end of the function would also had removed the warning.  However the user of the function would need to determine if a default constructed return value means that the argument_name can(not) be found.
